# How to get away with Extra space between Caption and linked Word Tables when using Autocaption option?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When using Autocaption option in Microsoft Word (as stated  [here](https://word.tips.net/T000891_Automatically_Adding_Captions.html)), a extra space is created above tables which has been linked from Excel to Word(for example via Past Special/Past link/HTMl format). Is there a remedy to get away with this extra space?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot about this problem? Try to check the line spacing or if you can delete the space.

Comment: @Lee I have added the screenshot (see the link). As can be seen the extra space (highlighted one) cannot be deleted. (there is no paragraph mark to select and delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image, the spacing is added not by the table, but by the caption.

1. Place the cursor at "Figure 2".
2. On the Home tab, select the arrow on the Paragragh section.
3. On the paragraph window, reduce the After spacing. Press OK

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was solved.

Comment: @SoroushKalantari Please mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).